# Issue in executing testcases in TestNG(java)

Tags: java

How to run other tests in TestNG after one test is failed using Java

For example:

```
@Test(priority=1)
    public void Online1(){
//code     
}

@Test(priority=2)
    public void Online2(){
//code     
}
```

In the above code, if priority 1 fails then priority 2 automatically get failed, I want to execute priority 2 even if 1 gets failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TestNG's `alwaysRun` attribute. This is quite self explanatory.

```
@Test(alwaysRun=true) 
  {
      //TestCode.
  }
```